Field from "dummy" node gets updated
I am trying to implement evenOddMerge solution to the problem (grouping together firstly odd indexed nodes, then even indexed nodes, e.g. from 2->5->3->1->8->4->6 should be 2->3->8->6->5->1->4). And I am missing how one piece of code gets updated, namely Node save=dummy2.next; and save field still gets updated even save belongs to "dummy" node which should not be related to any other reference even though its next element holds reference to head.next I thought. Below is my piece of code (only doing first part of task, grouping together odd nodes, and save fields somehow still gets updated) 
public static Node evenOddMerge(Node nx) {
    Node dummy=new Node(-1);
            Node iter=dummy;
            Node h=iter;
            
            Node n=nx;
            Node dummy2=new Node(-1);
            dummy2.next=nx.next;
            Node save=dummy2.next;
            
            while(n.next!=null && n.next.next!=null) {
                iter.next=n;
                n=n.next.next;
                iter=iter.next;
            }
            if(n!=null) {
                iter.next=n;
                iter=iter.next;
            }
            
            Node n2=save;

Was wondering if someone knows why save field still gets changed, when it originated from dummy node, I thought being in dummy node prevents it from being modified.

There are objects (such as a Node, coming into existance by instantiation, e.g. new Node(-1). Then there are variables of type Node referring to an object (or none). Assigning the value of one such variable to another doesn't create a copy, but has another variable referring to one and the same object. You change it, it is changed, regardless of the reference used to access it.

Thank you for reading and the comment. Do you mean dummy node can still be updated even when i don't iterate through it, and only his dummy.next i am trying to save? and creating new Node to be dummy does not help with avoiding iterating through it?

Revisiting this, I think you have a misconception rather than a programming problem. I think it would be best disspelled with a few diagrams; alas, I don't feel up to that. (FWIW, I don't understand your "comment question" from the comma to the end.)

i was thinking it was possible to create dummy node and then dummy.next to assign node we want to save and reuse later. So when we use that node's value unless we iterate through dummy it won't be changed? But that is not how it works now i think.
